# IIS app pool application asks for password (basic auth) but neither postman or insomnia can respond

Tags: iis, postman, basic-authentication, insomnia

We have an IIS server running a EPICOR ERP system. The ERP system installs IIS application pool, which certain urls are remapped to be handled by the app pool.

Here is what it says about the verification:

For security reasons you should always use https with REST API

> REST API supports 2 authentication methods Basic authentication The
>   username and password are combined into a string separated by a colon
>   and encoded using Base64. The result is placed into Authorization
>   header: Authorization: Basic {encoded string} Token authentication The
>   bearer token can be obtained for the user from token service. See
>   https://epicorapp2/ERP10.1Test/TokenResource.svc/help (Token
>   authentication should be enabled). Then access token should be send in
>   the Authorization header in the following form: Authorization: Bearer
>   {token string}

The IIS server itself has anonymous authentication for the top level url (and all others are turned off).

My experience in Chrome when I go to the desired URL:

https://epicorapp2/ERP10.1Test/api/help/

is that one gets a pop-up asking for username/password (where the user/passord is for the ERP system, not for the host IIS system).

But I am unable to duplicate this experience either with Postman or Insomnia
(I have tried putting in the username/password in the authorization options for both Postman and Insomnia. I get a 401 authorization error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got postman to work. But Insomnia works fine as soon as I was able to update the self-sign certificate to DigiCert.